# Synchronized build numbers

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have 3 jobs:

1. Debug version (after commits).
2. QA version (manual, timer).
3. Release version (triggered by 2, manual).

Builds from second job should have BUILD_NUMBER larger by one than newest build from first job, and when second job triggered third job then he should have the same BUILD_NUMBER as second. When third job will be triggered manual, then he also should have BUILD_NUMBER larger by one than newest build from first job.

I hope that what I wrote is understandable ;P

I wrote script in groovy:

```
import jenkins.model.*

jenkinsInstance = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance

searchedJobName = "^synchronize_build_numbers.*"
jobName = "synchronize_build_numbers_qa"
allItems = jenkinsInstance.items
if ("${JOB_NAME}" == jobName) {
    chosenJob = allItems.findAll{ job -> job.name.matches("synchronize_build_numbers_release") }
    chosenJob.each{ job -> job.nextBuildNumber = "${BUILD_NUMBER}".toInteger() }
} else {
    chosenJobs = allItems.findAll{ job -> job.name.matches(searchedJobName) }
    buildNumber = chosenJobs.collect{ job -> job.nextBuildNumber }.max()
    chosenJobs.each{ job -> job.nextBuildNumber = buildNumber }
}

return [:]
```

And it works, but I would like to make this script was more universal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! According to your question, your script works. It's not clear what you are asking for help with. Stack Overflow is great when you have a specific question, but it's hard for us to provide help with "how can I make this better" questions. If you're looking for a code review, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I want use script in another jobs, so I wonder if it is possible to pass arguments to script with searched job name etc. in Jenkins ;)